# Replace string in entire document source code

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML document, with a string that I want to replace. Here are the strings (`9673`):

```
<meta property="og:description" content="***April &amp;nbsp;9673&amp;nbsp;" />
<span class="agent-phone-number">+5 9673</span>
<a href="#shownumber" class="js-agent-phone-number"><span class="agent-phone-number" data-mobile="9673">9673</span></a>
<span class="agent-phone-number">+5 9673</span>
<li><a href="sms:9673" class="js-agent-phone-number-sms"><i class="pgicon pgicon-comment-o"></i>SMS</a></li>
```

Post loading a document, I want to inject a Javascript to replace the string `9673` to `0000`. How do I do that? I only need the Javascript part where it searches entire HTMLL document and replaces the string.

Comment: Are you asking how to "inject a JavaScript" - or how to replace a string-value in every attribute value and `#text` node - or both?

Comment: Not asking how to inject javascript. Lemme edit my question.

Comment: you are talking about parsing the html, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick-to-write, slow-to-run answer is to abuse `innerHTML`:

```
function replace_9673_everywhere() {
    
    const documentHtml = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
    const newDocumentHtml = documentHtml.replace( /9673/g, '0000' );
    document.documentElement.innerHTML = newDocumentHtml;
}
```

...but this will probably break the document because it will make the browser re-parse everything (so any current page script-state with DOM element references will be broken).

---

A better approach is to traverse the DOM as this won't trigger a reparse provided you manipulate `Element.attributes` and `Element.textContent` (and `#text` nodes individually) and avoid using `innerHTML` / `outerHTML` entirely:

```
function replace_9673_everywhere() {
    const rootNode = document.documentElement;
    replace_9673_in_element( rootNode );
}

function replace_9673_in_element( el ) {
    // Replace in attributes:
    for( let i = 0; i < el.attributes.length; i++ ) {
        const attr = el.attributes.item(i);
        if( attr.value.includes( '9673' ) ) {
            attr.value = attr.value.replace( /9673/g, '0000' );
        }
    } 

    // Replace in child nodes (not just Element children):
    for( const childNode of el.childNodes ) {
        if( childNode.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE ) {
            if( childNode.textContent.includes( '9673' ) ) {
                childNode.textContent = childNode.textContent.replace( /9673/g, '0000' );
            }
        }
        else if( childNode.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE ) {
            replace_9673_in_element( childNode );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can skip the regex and do a simple replaceAll()

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava Browser support for `String.prototype.replaceAll` is still lacking: https://caniuse.com/?search=replaceAll (as of September 2020, it's only supported by Firefox 77+, Chromium 85 browsers (which was released only a couple of weeks ago) and Safari 13+, excluding the current versions of Opera and Android Firefox.

Comment: `childNode.nodeType` will always be a number, not a string, so the comparisons will always evaluate to `false`. You can use the enum values under `Node` instead: `childNode.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE` and `childNode.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE`

Comment: @LionelRowe Derp, thank you! Sorry, it was 3am when I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach, using `TreeWalker`s, that targets text nodes and attributes only, without messing with the actual HTML structure.

```js
function* iterateNodes(walker) {
    let next

    while (next = walker.nextNode()) {
        yield next
    }
}

const nodesUnder = (el, nodeFilters) => {
    const walker = document
        .createTreeWalker(el, nodeFilters)

    const nodes = iterateNodes(walker)

    return [...nodes]
}

const htmlEl = document.documentElement

const textNodes = nodesUnder(htmlEl, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT)

const attrNodes = nodesUnder(htmlEl, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT)
    .map(el => [...el.attributes])
    .flat()

;[...textNodes, ...attrNodes].forEach(node => {
    node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/9673/g, '0000')
})

console.log(document.querySelector('#outer').outerHTML)
```

```css
* { font-family: sans-serif }
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="changed-9673" data-attr="9673">9673 (changed)</div>
    <custom-element-9673>unchanged</custom-element-9673>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice approach (+1) - but I feel using the spread-operator `[...nodes]` with your custom generator-function `iterateNodes` is defeating the point of using a lazily-evaluated generator-function as this will eagerly-load all element references into memory at once. Why not simply `return nodes` inside `nodesUnder`?

Comment: The idea is that it _could_ be used lazily, but OP's use case doesn't call for it. Perhaps it's a little over-engineered for the use case, to be fair.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this

```js
function replace9673() {
  $("html").html($("html").html().replaceAll("9673", "0000"));
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta property="og:description" content="***April &amp;nbsp;9673&amp;nbsp;" />
</head>

<body>
<span class="agent-phone-number">+5 9673</span>
<a href="#shownumber" class="js-agent-phone-number"><span class="agent-phone-number" data-mobile="9673">9673</span></a>
<span class="agent-phone-number">+5 9673</span>
<li><a href="sms:9673" class="js-agent-phone-number-sms"><i class="pgicon pgicon-comment-o"></i>SMS</a></li>

<button onclick="replace9673()">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```